# Add license agreement to your iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, eula

How can I add an EULA to a free iOS app so that the user must agree before installing the app to their iPhone or iPad?
Is this possible through iTunesConnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to custom-roll your own (which still needs to comply with Apple's minimum requirements), you can change the EULA from Apple's default to your own in iTunes Connect.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brad, I included a custom EULA in iTunes Connect and it is shown under the "License Agreement" in the AppStore. But I would like the user to "Accept" the EULA before downloading and installing the app. If the user does not "Agree" the app should not install. How can I implement this in my iOS app?

Comment: If Apple doesn't require it at the iTunes level, you can't do anything pre-install. I would question whether your need is exceptional enough to require it; if so, make sure you note early in the app description that there are essential terms in the EULA that the user agrees to by installing the app (that is, call it out specifically).

Comment: How can it be done in the app? Can I do it using alert messages or is it part of the Xcode built settings?